# loop device not matching file size

Tags: partition, dd, loop-device, disk-image, sparse-files

I have a sparse backing file (NTFS) (made via `dd seek=`) that's a partial image of a damaged disk. The size as given by `ls` matches the original disk. However, when looping it, `/proc/partitions` shows it as about half the size as the original disk. It seems like `losetup` is ignoring the final sparse extend of the file because it has no data following it.

As a result, if I use `losetup -P` (or `kpartx`) the partitioning fails on a partition extending past the size given by `/proc/partitions`.

How can I resolve this without expanding the file? (Perhaps writing to the last sector will help, but I would like to avoid touching the image).

More info:

`cat /proc/partitions` (for the loop and the disk):

```
 7        5  264173760 loop5
 8        0  488386584 sda
```

`stat` on the backing file:

```
  File: gordon.dsk
  Size: 500107862016    Blocks: 31986416   IO Block: 4096   regular file
```

`lsblk --bytes`:

```
loop5       7:5    0  270513930240  1 loop
sda         8:0    0  500107862016  0 disk
```

`sfdisk` output:

```
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk gordon.dsk: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: {redacted}

Device          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
gordon.dsk1      2048   1230847   1228800   600M Windows recovery environment
gordon.dsk2   1230848   1845247    614400   300M EFI System
gordon.dsk3   1845248   2107391    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
gordon.dsk4   2107392 944205823 942098432 449.2G Microsoft basic data
gordon.dsk5 944205824 976773119  32567296  15.5G Windows recovery environment
```

Comment: Please add more details (`ls -l file`, `sfdisk -l file`, `/proc/partitions`, etc). Maybe you didn't extend it enough? notice that `dd` uses 512 bytes blocks.

Comment: I don't know this problem, but can you post your kernel version (`uname -r`) please?

Comment: add the output of `sfdisk -l your_backing_file` too (`sfdisk` doesn't need a device, also works with regular files).

Comment: @mosvy I already allocated the last sector as a workaround, but I believe it showed all the relevant partitions beforehand...

Comment: @sourcejedi 4.15.0-36-generic

Comment: ok, I see that  you don't want to show the `sfdisk -l file` output under any circumstances, so I won't bother you anymore ;-)

Comment: @mosvy please be civil. It sounds like the file does not have this problem anymore, if so there is no point re-running `sfdisk` with the `-l` option.

Comment: @sourcejedi why are you accusing me of incivility? what are you up to? Do not try to **falsely** suggest that I was rude in a comment I then deleted. As to OP's problem, I wasn't able to reproduce it in any way yet, but I'm waiting for your answer ;-)

Comment: Voted to close this question, since the original problem has been removed by a method that the OP was originally trying to avoid, and no-one else has found a way to reproduce the issue so we can investigate.